# How to read GTM216(Graduate Texts in Mathematics: Matrices: Theory and Application)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm studying Axiomatic Linear Algebra and the text book is GTM216.
But I found it is too hard to understand, even in the 1st page.

For example, the third line in the page 1 is  “There are also finite fields, such as Fρ:= Z / ρZ”

I know what is field. But I really don't know what are those symbols meaning and I don't know which material I should refer to.

I only took basic undergraduate level linear algebra and didn't take abstract algebra.

So When I was reading this book, I got stuck almost every 5 or 6 lines. It's really frustrating but I really need to read this book and understand it.

I think this is because I missed some prerequisites.

Can anyone help me out or let me know which books/materials/blogs/websites that I could use to help me to understand this book?

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: It sounds like the book is too hard for where you are right now, you can try extensively googling the bits you are missing, but there is a ton you don't have which is taught over the course of entire courses with lectures and feedback, it will be very slow going trying to integrate it from where you are.

Comment: If you are taking it in a class, I would recommend going to the instructor or TA for help.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about finite fields.  All you really need to know is that whatever your "numbers" are, we can add/subtract/multiply/divide.  If you come across a question specifically about finite fields, then you should perhaps ask around.  In any case, $\Bbb Z/ p\Bbb Z$ just means "the integers modulo $p$".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" before jumping to a GTM textbook. It's much more theoretical/abstract than most first courses in linear algebra.

Comment: It doesn't really say anything about finite fields though